# django & jython

Tags: python, django, jython

I'm new to django and jython. So, I have a very basic question. Is it possible to run java applications using jython in django framework? I've got jython installed and django running on my machine, and I'm trying to write an applet. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: An applet? As in a Java web applet? Those don't run on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest development documentation has a complete chapter covering Django and Jython:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/jython/

And you can also check the python wiki on jython:
http://wiki.python.org/jython/DjangoOnJython

Comment: Those links got me no where. I didn't find a installer on that site.  I bounced around in google to find one. After I installed the version, I see that pip still isn't installed out of the box.  So, I still need to find a way to install pip, so I can install Django. But that doesn't work  your answer isn't that good.

Comment: pitchblack408: What do you mean by "that doesn't work"? What OS are you on? Installing pip is really easy, just download the get-pip.py and run it on your system, as outlined in http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html 

Keep in mind that the original question and answer is more than 3 years old, both Jython and Django might have introduced changes since then.